# Removing multiple xml notes with attribute?

Tags: php, xml, dom

i have this code

```
$doc = new DOMDocument; 
$doc->load('Clans/' . $_POST['s']);

$thedocument = $doc->documentElement;

//this gives you a list of the messages
$list = $thedocument->getElementsByTagName('member');
foreach($_POST['delete_unit'] as $unit_id){
$nodeToRemove = null;
foreach ($list as $domElement){
  $attrValue = $domElement->getAttribute('id');
  if ($attrValue == $unit_id) {
    $nodeToRemove = $domElement; //will only remember last one- but this is just an example :)
  }
}
}

//Now remove it.
if ($nodeToRemove != null)
$thedocument->removeChild($nodeToRemove);

$doc->saveXML('Clans/' . $_POST['s']);
```

POST['delete_unit'] is array of ids
why this is not working or is there better way to do this

error code PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to DOMDocument::saveXML() must be an instance of DOMNode, string given in

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to DOMDocument::saveXML() must be an instance of DOMNode, string given in

Comment: What does contain 'Clans/' . $_POST['s']? Is it a file? Are you trying to save you'r new XML inside it?

Comment: $_POST['s'] is my xml file which i'm trying to edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the last line, I think you're looking for

```
file_put_contents('Clans/' . $_POST['s'], $doc->saveXML());
```

If no arguments are passed, [`saveXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) returns the full document as a string.

You also need to look into sanitising your form inputs!